# Laschen in Computerprogrammen

Tags: swiss-standard-german

In der Schweiz ist bei der Beschreibung von Computerprogrammen (Benutzerhandbücher, User Support) oft von *Laschen* die Rede.

Beispiel:

> Wechseln Sie auf die *Lasche* "Übersicht"

Was soll das sein?

Comment: Da der Zusammenhang fehlt ... ich kenne es als Bezeichnung für Register/Reiter/Tabscheet.

Comment: @bummi Immer dieser Kontext ... Hab' ein Beispiel hinzugefügt.

Comment: @bummi ... und auch ansonsten liegst Du natürlich richtig

Comment: Interessant wäre an dieser Stelle, ob Schweizer auch das physische Vorbild (nämlich die Schildchen an Hängeregistraturen (http://www.edigitech.de/shop7/images/products/main/leitz-klein-aktei-haengeregistratur-korb-schwarz.jpg)) auch als "Lasche" bezeichnen. Weiß das jemand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da der Zusammenhang hergestellt wurde...
Gemeint ist [die Registerkarte](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registerkarte) oder üblicher der **Reiter**.

Comment: Man kann durchaus auch [*"der/das Tab"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tab_Registerkarte_Einteilung) sagen, das wird je nach Alter mitunter besser verstanden als die eingedeutschten *"Lasche, Reiter, Registerkarte"*.

Comment: @Takkat richtig, auch Sheet und Folder sind bei vielen unserer Kunden die geläufigen Bezeichnungen.

Comment: @bummi Eine unserer Kundinnen verwendet den begriff Tasche für Tabs...